# How to change the resolution of a rendered image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, camera, resolution

I'm looking to make my rendered image a higher resolution. I've tried a few things but nothing has seemed to work yet. As you can see by the reference image its pretty pixelated.

[image]

Comment: hello, it's in the Output panel > Dimensions > Resolution

Comment: Properties editor > Output tab > Format panel > resolution.  https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/dev/render/output/properties/format.html

Comment: You fast @moonboots heh

Comment: Moonboots is a goddamn hero. Thankyou guys

Comment: @L0Lock, I know, sorry  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Go into the *Output panel > Format > Resolution*